# SQL include results where id does not exists in related table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am struggling with an SQL query. This situation is as follows:-

I have 2 tables Users and Results:-

**Users**

- user_id (PK)

**Results**

- result_id
- fk module_id

I am trying to select all users from the Results table who don't have an entry for module 1.

I can select all users with no corresponding record using the following:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN results r 
    ON u.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE isnull(r.result_id);
```

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to ignore all rows in the Results table who have a module id that is not 1.

Do I need a subquery?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Subquery is not required, you can do it in the same query. Which database is this MSSQL, Mysql or Oracle or any other? According to Db query can be formed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said - it's mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user U
LEFT OUTER JOIN results R ON R.user_id = U.user_id
WHERE R.result_id IS NULL
    OR(R.result_id IS NOT NULL AND R.module_id <> 1)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Joel, Many thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately that still returned users who had a result for module 1 as well as all the users who don't.

Comment: I changed my answer, can you test it? I moved the test from the JOIN clause to the WHERE clause in order to exclude every rows without correspondance in table results AND rows that have a correspondance with module_id 1.

Comment: That's great Joel! That seems to have done the trick! many thanks for your time.

Comment: Good news! It's a pleasure to see that my answer helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to JOIN all users to their results unless the result happens to be module #1, you can use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN results r ON 
    u.user_id = r.user_id AND 
    r.module_id != 1;
```

I'm not completely clear on whether you want all users and associated non-module 1 results, or if you're just looking for those users who have no entry for module 1 whatsoever.  If that's what you're looking for, then using NOT IN (or NOT EXISTS, which would be faster - can't remember if MySQL supports it) would be the solution, e.g.,

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u
WHERE u.user_id NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM results
    WHERE module_id = 1
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had already accepted an answer above which works but your second example also achieves exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you found an answer!  Still a little unsure which you wanted: my second example returns users who never had a module 1 result, the accepted answer looks like it returns users who have a result other than module #1 (which, if users can have more than one module, is not the same thing).

Comment: Oh,I'd better look a little closer - I wanted all users who have no module 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

If this mysql then Try with this

```
SELECT * 
FROM user U
LEFT OUTER JOIN results R ON R.user_id = U.user_id              
WHERE R.result_id IS NULL OR (R.result_id IS NOT NULL AND R.module_id != 1)
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that previously and it returns no results at all.

Comment: I believe that's because you can't have both a NULL ResultID and a ModuleID that's not a specific value ...